# Is there a way to force the user to fill in a field in the standard Sign-Up form in Azure B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm using the Sign Up user flow. I'm only asking for a Display Name from the user. This claim is passed to the web service the first time the user accesses it and the web service creates a new entry in the 'User' table with this name. However, I can't seem to get the flow to validate that something was entered, so if the user skips this field, I get a 'null' for a user name.

Is there any way to perform basic validation on the Sign Up form in B2C? Just a rule to make sure that something was entered before they finish the flow?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

<`InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="username" Required="true"/>`

Required="true" forces some kind of input.

Or add a [restriction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema#emailbox) to the claim type.

Comment: Where is this located? In the manifest?

Comment: No, in the sign-up technical policy. Just change the "signInName" to whatever your field is called. The main point is adding Required="true". "PartnerClaimType" is optional.